# Printing a vector row by row

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, shiny, paste

I am working on a Shiny App and want to print the top 3 rows under my Graphs.

I made it to create a reactive df that contains only the selected data and short it with `head(df, 3)`.

df

```
    Letter   Number
1     a        1
2     b        2
3     c        3
4     d        4
5     e        5
```

Printing this df it will show me the data but in a wrong format. At the moment it is like this

```
c(a, b, c) c(1, 2, 3)
```

I would like to see my df row by row.

```
col1   col 2
 a       1
 b       2
 c       3
```

Do you have any idea to achieve it? I cannot believe that it is hard to do but i can't find a fitting solution.

I just want to paste it in a `verbatimTextOutput` :(

Comment: [Minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal code for what you are trying to achieve:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  verbatimTextOutput('text')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(Letter = letters[1:5], Number = 1:5 )
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this code your output is as follows:

[image]

Hope it helps!